# Tomcat, Spring, Hibernate App - Users reporting session mix-up

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

We are using Tomcat 6, Spring 3.1 and Hibernate. Everything works except that users are reporting their sessions getting mixed up. This only happens when our app is used within one classroom or behind one proxy. Any ideas on where to start to debug this issue. Our app uses Spring Security but stores and uses the user object from the session and NOT the Authentication object.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Check the JSESSIONID cookie in the browser. There are chances that it is being overriden

Comment: Yes, the JSESSIONID seems to be overriden. Not sure how and where. The  user bean is a regular POJO that has hibernate annotations.

Answer (score 0):

https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-3502 ?